# Why won't my bootstrap button format properly

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap

I am using bootstrap to style my site and I want to use it to style my search field. When I do the button looks like a large square instead of the rounded button that's supposed to go with the search field. heres the code

```
  {{-- Navigation --}}
      <nav class="navbar navbar-default navbar-custom navbar-fixed-top">
<div class="container-fluid">
{{-- Brand and toggle get grouped for better mobile display --}}
    <div class="navbar-header page-scroll">
        <button type="button" class="navbar-toggle" data-toggle="collapse"
                data-target="#navbar-main">
            <span class="sr-only">Toggle navigation</span>
            <span class="icon-bar"></span>
            <span class="icon-bar"></span>
            <span class="icon-bar"></span>
        </button>
        <a class="navbar-brand" href="/">{{ config('blog.name') }}</a>
    </div>

    {{-- Collect the nav links, forms, and other content for toggling --}}
    <div class="collapse navbar-collapse" id="navbar-main">
        <ul class="nav navbar-nav">
            <li>
                <a href="/">Home</a>
            </li>
        </ul>
        <ul class="nav navbar-nav">
            <li>
                <a href="/contact">Contact</a>
            </li>
        </ul>

        <div class="col-sm-3 col-md-3 pull-right">
            <form class="navbar-form" role="search">
                <div class="input-group">
                    <input type="text" class="form-control" placeholder="Search" name="srch-term" id="srch-term">
                    <div class="input-group-btn">
                        <button class="btn btn-default" type="submit"><i class="glyphicon glyphicon-search"></i></button>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </form>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

The css is the standard css with nothing altered. Tried to paste it but it slowed my computer down. Can anyone suggest what I could do to rectify this?

[Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/xkya3f2m/)

Comment: div.input-group-btn button { border-radius:5px;}. It will give it a round looking kind of corner. Also, you can use the dev tool in you browser to play around with the css and see how the button behaves as you play with the CSS rules. In addition, you have to make sure that bootstrap is added properly to your template or master page.

Comment: I created you a fiddle http://jsfiddle.net/xkya3f2m/, which part is incorrect again? which bootstrap version are you using? what browser are you using? can you post your css declaration as well?

Comment: @choz I also created a fiddle https://jsfiddle.net/gbup8ugc/ but can't see what is wrong.

Comment: @choz I updated your fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/xkya3f2m/1/

Included bootstrap.js so that we can actually open the menu. It looks fine in there. So for the Original Poster, his site styling is messing up and overriding bootstrap default stylings.

Comment: @AlboBest  Actually, I was too lazy to incude that.. So I just resized the fiddle's result area bigger so it'd show up :D.. gj btw..

Comment: @choz  Best I am using chrome browser and the latest bootstrap

Comment: @losee Can't you inspect on your browser what style is it using from your browser? Or you can post your whole code on pastebin or something, so we can help you.